# Scraper - How to save and store emoji

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, emoji, scrape

I am currently using Scraper from https://scrapy.org/ under python 3.x and ubuntu environment ,
somehow i would like to get user comment in forum, and which contain text as well as emoji.

Wondering how we save those emoji into an array so that i can see this in cvs or json ?

Thanks

Comment: Add the html which you want to scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be good if you can at least provide the HTML of the page.

If emoji and text are enclosed in a parent element, let's say div with comment class like below.

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="description">This is a comment.</div>
    <span>:-)</span>
</div>
```

then you can use the following XPath or CSS selector.

```
response.css('.comment ::text').extract()
```

or

```
response.xpath('.//div[@class="comment"]//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it caused by HTML structure. If emoji provided in the sub-element you can use `string()` function in your `xpath` expression.

```
response.xpath('string(.//xpath/to/comment)')
```